# SQL Server - Second highest sales query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I'm working on this question:**

> Show the manufacturer with the 2nd top sales in the year of 2009 and the manufacturer with the 2nd top sales in the year of 2010.

I tried finding the 2nd top manufacturer in terms of sales but I got a lot of errors. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

**Here is my code:**

```
select
  top 1 dim_date.year,
  dim_model.idmanufacturer,
  sum(fact_transactions.totalprice)
from
  (
    select
      top 2 dim_date.year,
      dim_model.idmanufacturer,
      sum(fact_transactions.totalprice)
    from
      fact_transactions
      join dim_date on dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
      join dim_model on dim_model.idmodel = fact_transactions.idmodel
    where
      dim_date.year = 2009
    Group by
      dim_date.year,
      dim_model.idmanufacturer
    Order by
      sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) Desc
  ) RESULT
Order by
  sum(fact_transactions.totalprice);
```

**And here are the error messages:**

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 77
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'Result'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
The multi-part identifier "dim_date.year" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
The multi-part identifier "dim_model.idmanufacturer" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
The multi-part identifier "fact_transactions.totalprice" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
The multi-part identifier "fact_transactions.totalprice" could not be bound.
```

Comment: give name to selected column sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) test

Comment: @DeepakKumar - this doesn't help still got errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code and let me know if any error occur.

```
SELECT TOP 1 year, 
             idmanufacturer, 
             test 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 dim_date.year, 
                     dim_model.idmanufacturer, 
                     Sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) test 
        FROM   fact_transactions 
               JOIN dim_date 
                 ON dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date 
               JOIN dim_model 
                 ON dim_model.idmodel = fact_transactions.idmodel 
        WHERE  dim_date.year = 2009 
        GROUP  BY dim_date.year, 
                  dim_model.idmanufacturer 
        ORDER  BY Sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) DESC) RESULT 
ORDER  BY test;
```

If there is any issue then please create SQL fiddle.

Comment: This ran properly just ORDER  BY Sum(fact_transactions.totalprice);  by Test

What is the reason for that as the codes look identical ?

Comment: Also if I add an IN operator          WHERE  dim_date.year = 2009  to where dim_date.year in (2009,2010) will it give me a result for both years ? Or still give me an error ?

Comment: There is difference of scope. In inner query you have all tables. But outer query you have one table(wrapper table) RESULT. So fact_transactions.totalprice will not work

Comment: In operator will work fine. No issue in that. Just identify the scope. Logic you know better than me. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepak !

Answer (score 0):

limit 1,1 for 2nd element, limit 2,1 for 3rd element and so on..

Can you please try this.

```
select dim_date.year, dim_model.idmanufacturer, sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) from fact_transactions join dim_date on dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date join dim_model on dim_model.idmodel =fact_transactions.idmodel where dim_date.year = 2009 Group by dim_date.year, dim_model.idmanufacturer Order by sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) Desc ) RESULT Order by sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) limit 1,1;
```

Comment: I think something is missing in the code 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 99
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: LIMIT is not valid in SQL Server, instead use TOP or ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to do something similar to this :

```
SELECT 
  [year]
, Manufacturer
, TotalPrice
FROM (
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idmanufacturer ORDER BY [year] ASC, TotalPrice DESC) RN
FROM (
    SELECT
      dim_date.year 
    , dim_model.idmanufacturer Manufacturer
    , SUM(fact_transactions.totalprice) TotalPrice
    FROM 
        fact_transactions 
    JOIN dim_date  ON dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
    JOIN dim_model ON dim_model.idmodel =fact_transactions.idmodel
    where 
         dim_date.year IN(2009,2010)
    GROUP BY 
      dim_date.year 
    , dim_model.idmanufacturer      
 ) RESULT
) D
WHERE 
    RN = 2
```

The steps :

1. Get the SUM of TotalPrice for each manufacture in year 2009 and 2010.
2. Order the results using ROW_NUMBER() to get an order number that can be selected easily.
3. Finalize the results by selecting the 2nd top sales for each Manufacturer.

**Explanation :**

The first query :

```
SELECT
  dim_date.year 
, dim_model.idmanufacturer Manufacturer
, SUM(fact_transactions.totalprice) TotalPrice
FROM 
    fact_transactions 
JOIN dim_date  ON dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
JOIN dim_model ON dim_model.idmodel =fact_transactions.idmodel
where 
     dim_date.year IN(2009,2010)
GROUP BY 
  dim_date.year 
, dim_model.idmanufacturer
```

Will summarize all dim_model.idmanufacturer transactions in year 2009 and 2010 and would sum up total price for each idmanufacturer in that period.

Then, we enclose it in a sub-query so we can reorder the results to our advantage using ROW_NUMBER() and order the results (number them) by year and total price for each idmanufacturer.

```
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idmanufacturer ORDER BY [year] ASC, TotalPrice DESC) RN
FROM (
    SELECT
      dim_date.year 
    , dim_model.idmanufacturer Manufacturer
    , SUM(fact_transactions.totalprice) TotalPrice
    FROM 
        fact_transactions 
    JOIN dim_date  ON dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
    JOIN dim_model ON dim_model.idmodel =fact_transactions.idmodel
    where 
         dim_date.year IN(2009,2010)
    GROUP BY 
      dim_date.year 
    , dim_model.idmanufacturer      
 ) RESULT
) D
```

This method would expand our chances from getting the results that we need in any position we want. For your request, we will get the second top sale (which is the second row) for each Manufacturer. So if they asked you to get the 3rd, 5th, or even the 10th. You can just reuse the same query and just change the rn from 2 to whatever position you want.

Comment: Could You please explain
"GROUP BY 
      dim_date.year 
    , dim_model.idmanufacturer      
 ) RESULT
) D
WHERE 
    RN = 2"
What is ")D" here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
select
  dim_date.year,
  dim_model.idmanufacturer,
  sum(fact_transactions.totalprice)
from
  (
    select
      row_number() over ( order by sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) desc ) as rowNumber,
      dim_date.year,
      dim_model.idmanufacturer,
      sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) as total
    from
      fact_transactions
      join dim_date on dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
      join dim_model on dim_model.idmodel = fact_transactions.idmodel
    Group by
      dim_date.year,
      dim_model.idmanufacturer
  ) RESULT
where
  RESULT.rowNumber = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for sql-server:

```
select
    res2.*
from
    (
    select
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    ORDER BY
        res1.price ) rank_price
    from
        (
        select
            dim_date.year,
            dim_model.idmanufacturer,
            sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) price
        from
            fact_transactions
        join dim_date on
            dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
        join dim_model on
            dim_model.idmodel = fact_transactions.idmodel
        where
            dim_date.year = 2009
        Group by
            dim_date.year,
            dim_model.idmanufacturer ) res1 ) res2
where
    rank_price = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select dim_date.year,
  dim_model.idmanufacturer,
  sum(fact_transactions.totalprice)
from
  fact_transactions
  join dim_date on dim_date.date = fact_transactions.date
  join dim_model on dim_model.idmodel = fact_transactions.idmodel
where
  dim_date.year = 2009
Group by
  dim_date.year,
  dim_model.idmanufacturer
Order by
  sum(fact_transactions.totalprice) Desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

This ANSI/ISO standard functionality has been available since SQL Server 2012.  [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/) is one place to learn more about it.